# How can I right align numbers in an ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, silverlight

In the xaml I have :

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"  x:Name="SelectedCountCollection"  ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedCountList}" Foreground="Purple" Margin="0,0,1,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

I end up with data looking like so :

```
20                   

5                      

7
```

I need to shift the 5 to the unit's position. I need to shift 7 to the unit's position.

Comment: Define an `ItemTemplate` for the `ItemsControl` and [set the alignment](https://imgur.com/yNNvsO8) you want there. Don't spam tag your question both `wpf` and `silverlight` because the solution for each case might be different.